# where is the logic wrong?

Tags: c, algorithm

i wrote a `memoized` code for computing factorial of a number in C . But on giving the input as `n=3` it gives the output as `6! = 134513904` .Can someone please explain what is going wrong?

```
int fact(int n)
{
int temp;
static int lookup_table[100];
if(lookup_table[n])
    return lookup_table[n]; 
else if(n == 0 )
{
    lookup_table[0]= 1;
    return 1;
}   
else
{
    temp = n * fact(n-1);
    lookup_table[n] = temp;
    return temp;
}

}
```

Comment: You still aren't initializing `lookup_table`. You need `static int lookup_table[100] = {0};`.

Comment: isn't that static array filled with memory garbage?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend checking the input against the bounds of the lookup table - if (n < 100 && lookup_table[n]) - to avoid a segfault.

Comment: @steve Is the array does not get initialosed to zero automatically as soon as I declare it static?

Comment: When I compiled and ran it, I got `6` as output when `n=3`. How are you calling it?

Comment: Can you post a complete compilable example, including the main() function?

Comment: `int main(void)    
{    
int n,result;  
printf("\nEnter n: ");  
scanf("%d",&n);  
result = fact(n);  
printf("\n%d! = %d\n",result);  
return 0;  
}`  then I say n = 3

Comment: Sorry, you're right, since you were seeing garbage I briefly assumed that rule applies only at file scope, but it's all objects with static storage duration.

Comment: @user567797: if that's your real `printf` statement, you're only passing one arg to be substituted, but you need two (for two instances of `%d` in the format string).

Comment: @steve Thanks man that seems to fix the bug.Don't know why these silly mistakes happen too often to me and when it happens it becomes so hard to track them down urrghhhhhh.....

Comment: @user567797 the printf is wrong. you want it like this: print("\n%d! = %d\n", n, result);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your printf (from a comment) doesn't have the correct number of arguments, and therefore prints a garbage value:

```
printf("\n%d! = %d\n",result);
```

Contrary to what others have said, the array doesn't have to be initialized explicitly, as the C standard says:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly,its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive orunsigned) zero
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules
> - if it is a union, the ﬁrst named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

However, it's good pratice to initialize explicitly in order to make your intentions clear.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>One problem could be that you don't ever initialize your table, so it is filled with whatever happens to be in memory.</strike>

Edit: Ah, it seems I'm wrong and that the behavior is well defined:

> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has
>   arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type
>   were assigned a null pointer constant.

[Source](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt)

Comment: But static variables are initialized to zero (if no explicit initialization is given) according to the C standard.

Comment: initialising it zero by writing `static int lookup_table[100] = {0}` doesn't seem to help!

Answer (score 0):

Like I suspected, problem is with the `printf` and not the function.